# Protobuf-related unit tests passing on my local machine but failing in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, serialization, protocol-buffers, timecop

I have a set of unit tests for serializer objects in my Rails application.  These serializer objects use the `google-protobuf (~> 3.5)` gem, including the `Google::Protobuf::Timestamp` object.  For time-related attributes (like `purchase_order#created_at`, `line_item#created_at`, and `inspection_event#event_occured_at`), we use a TimeSerializer object, implemented as follows:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module ProtoSerializers
  class TimeSerializer < BaseProtoSerializer
    def serialize
      return if object.nil?

      GOOGLE_BASE::Timestamp.new(seconds: object&.to_i, nanos: object&.nsec)
    end
  end
end
```

This is instantiated by calling `ProtoSerializers::TimeSerializer.serialize(time)`, where `time` is a Rails Time or DateTime object.

The tests compare expected results of the serialization with the actual results, pass if the results match, and fail otherwise:

```
describe '#serialize an inspection whose purchase order and line item are both archived' do

  subject { described_class.serialize(object) }

  let(:purchase_order) { create(:purchase_order, :is_archived) }
  let(:line_item) { create(:line_item, :archived, purchase_order: purchase_order) }
  let(:object) { create(:inspection, line_item: line_item) }

  it 'serializes attributes' do
    expect(subject).to be_a(MyCorp::Proto::MyApp::InspectionEvent)

    expect(subject).to have_attributes(
      ...(misc key-value pairs)...
      purchase_order: ProtoSerializers::PurchaseOrderSerializer.serialize(purchase_order),
      line_item: ProtoSerializers::LineItemSerializer.serialize(line_item),
      event_occurred_at: ProtoSerializers::TimeSerializer.serialize(object.event_occurred_at)
    )
  end
end
```

The `PurchaseOrder` and `LineItem` models both have `created_at` attributes, as per standard Rails practice.

This test passes on my machine but fails when I push it up to Github (which kicks off a Jenkins test pipeline).  The expected-vs-actual diff appears as follows:

```
20:00:39        -:line_item => <MyCorp::Proto::MyApp::LineItem: ..., created_at: <Google::Protobuf::Timestamp: seconds: 1522368034, nanos: 909710602>, ...>,
20:00:39        +:line_item => <MyCorp::Proto::MyApp::LineItem: ..., created_at: <Google::Protobuf::Timestamp: seconds: 1522368034, nanos: 909710000>, ...>,
20:00:39        -:purchase_order => <MyCorp::Proto::MyApp::PurchaseOrder: ..., created_at: <Google::Protobuf::Timestamp: seconds: 1522368034, nanos: 909710602>>,
20:00:39        +:purchase_order => <MyCorp::Proto::MyApp::PurchaseOrder: ..., created_at: <Google::Protobuf::Timestamp: seconds: 1522368034, nanos: 909710000>>,
```

As you can see, the `seconds` attribute matches, but the `nanos` attrivute is off by a few hundred nanoseconds.  I've tried using Timecop in this test, as follows, but the failed tests persisted:

```
before { Timecop.freeze(Time.now) }

after { Timecop.return }
```

I'm not sure what could be different between the Jenkins pipeline and my machine.  I'm using a Macbook with an Intel Core i7 processor, which I believe is 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the cause is a loss of precision when converting 64-bit ints on my machine (Macbook with Intel Core i7 processor) to Protobufs 32-bit int nanoseconds.  In order to fix the problem, I had to mock the time to something where a loss of precision wouldn't be a factor.  In the end I used Epoch time, as follows:

```
before { Timecop.freeze(Time.at(0)) }

after { Timecop.return }
```

This solved the issue.